# Why is a class template instantiated when it's ot required to be a completely object type?

Tags: c++, templates

Class template can be either explicitly or implicitly intantiated and the class template is being instantiated implicitly if `N3797::14.7.1/1 [temp.inst]`

> Unless a class template specialization has been explicitly
>   instantiated (14.7.2) or explicitly specialized (14.7.3), the class
>   template specialization is implicitly instantiated when the
>   specialization is referenced in a context that requires a
>   completely-defined object type or when the completeness of the class
>   type affects the semantics of the program.

Let me provide an example when the context is not required the class type to be a completely defined:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct A
{
    void foo();
};

template<class T> void A<T>::foo(){ std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }

A<int>* a;
int main(){ a -> foo(); }
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af916a81465947fc)**

In that example the class template neither explicitly nor implicitly instantiated. So, we actually don't have the definition of the class `A<int>`. But despite the fact it works fine. Couldn't you explain that behavior.

Comment: You are calling `A<int>::foo()`, so you need a complete type. Doesn't the quote say that in this case the template is implicitly instantiated?

Comment: I suspect calling that function is going to require a properly typed `this` pointer and an addressable function pointer (also fully typed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[expr.ref]/p2, emphasis mine:

> For the second option (arrow) the first expression shall have pointer
>   to **complete** class type.

Why do you think it's a context that doesn't require a completely-defined object type?

Comment: Indeed, my bad. What I'm trying to achieve is to construct an example which will lead to a compiler/linker error if the template isn't instantiated explicitly. Is it possible

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Not in a valid program, unless it's a compiler bug, and it also probably need multiple translation units; [temp]/p6 might be useful.

Comment: As far as I understand we don't ever need to explicitly instantiate a template, because if we start using it in the context which requires a completely-defined object type, the template will be instantiated implicitly and therefore we'll get to use it as a complitely defined class or function.

Comment: @DmitryFucintv It's usually done to separate the implementation from the interface (or save compilation time with an explicit instantiation declaration).

Comment: This is unclear about the fact that a compiler doesn't know about explicit instatiation which is done in another translation unit. If we put explicit instantiation in another TU and the template appears in the context requires the template to be instatiated, will it be intatiated implicitly?

Comment: @DmitryFucintv Many implicit instantiations can be suppressed with an explicit instantiation declaration - [temp.explicit]/p10. You can also provide only a function template declaration in the header that is included in all TUs, and limit the definition along with the necessary explicit instantiations to one TU.

Answer (score 0):

See the example at [14.7.1/4](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) which demonstrates that `a -> foo();` is "a context that requires a completely-defined object type".